# Is there a Node.js HTTP Request Module?

Tags: node.js

Is there a module for creating HTTP Requests in node.js? I am hoping to implement it like this:

`var some-module = require('some-module')`

Comment: Does your computer have the google module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the "request" package. Simply include it in your project like this:

`var request = require('request')`

Remember to do `npm install request` in your terminal for your project's directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a request module present in NPM to create HTTP requests in Node.js.

**[npm request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)**

Hope this helps.